# how to use postgresql with ado.net entity framework in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, ado.net-entity-data-model

In my current project, we are using visual studio 2008, sql server 2008, mvc 2 with ado.net entity framework (ado.net entity data model), linq and developing a web application. This application working fine.

Now, we want to use PostgreSQL which is open source, so is it possible to change the database from Sql server 2008 to PostgreSQL.

I checked [devart](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/) and [npgsql](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/npgsql/) to implement the connectivity to postgresql database using entity data model.

When I checked devart, it supports entity data model in professional edition (which is licensed). And we dont want to use any licensed components.

When I checked npgsql, there are no examples or links which explain about connecting to postgresql using ado.net entity framework.

Now my question is, is it possible to implement postgresql, ado.net entity model, linq ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few months ago I worked on a project using postgresql, npgsql, EF and linq: so yes, is possible, but required a bit of work to set up it.

On http://npgsql.com/ there are few articles on how to handle it, but now the web site seem to have some mapping problems with the pages :)
So I link to you the google cached ones:

[Part1](http://google.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://npgsql.com/index.php/2009/08/how-to-set-up-entity-framework-npgsql-part-1/)

[Part2](http://google.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://npgsql.com/index.php/2009/11/how-to-set-up-entity-framework-npgsql-part-2/)

Comment: thanks dude, npgsql did the work and i followed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2007/12/07/how-to-use-your-existing-csdl-msl-ssdl-files-in-the-entity-designer-ctp2.aspx